# How to get href's caption and display it into a span?

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, title

I am loading different html pages on a div using jquery. What I wanna do is grab the caption of the link that is clicked and display it into a span(similar to fancybox functionality)

```
$(".iframe").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $mylink = $(this).attr('href');
        $mydiv.load($mylink)
});
```

html

```
<a class="iframe" href="page.html" caption="My title">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have tried this.. hope it helps.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9kyHU/4/)

html code: (change the href="/" for an html page IN YOUR SERVER)

```
<span id='mycaption'></span>
<br>
<div id="mydiv" style="width:300px; height: 300px"></div>
<br>
    <a class="iframe" href="/" caption="My title">link</a>
```

jquery code:

```
$(".iframe").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var mylink = $(this).attr('href');
        $("#mydiv").load(mylink);

        var mycap = $(this).attr('caption');
        $("#mycaption").html(mycap);
});
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, how didn't I think of this! hehe. Any idea how to navigate through the links(htmls) using next and previous buttons? Should I make another question for that?

Comment: @zefs better make another question, and don't forget to try to solve it for your own first :) Maybe you could use the attribute data-*, using `data-next` and `data-prev` with the next/prev url and get that with jquery.. `$('#next').data("next");`. Think about it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your span has an ID (Lets go with `test`)

```
$(".iframe").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $mylink = $(this).attr('href');
    $mydiv.load($mylink)

    //Span stuff
    var caption = this.caption;
    $("#test").html(caption);
```

});

Answer (score 1):

you have answer in your code itself. get the 'caption' as you are getting 'href'

```
$("#mySpan").html( $(this).attr("caption") );
```